# Приостановка или продолжение выполнения функции при переходе в фоновый режим

Tags: swift, функции

Использую функцию Парсинга данных с сайта

```
func pars(arg: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ()) {

do {


        myURL = URL(string: "https:_______")
        let html = try! String(contentsOf: myURL!, encoding: .utf8)
        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
        let body = doc.body()
        name = (try body?.select(".name"))!



    completion(arg)



} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}

}
```

Но при сворачивании приложения часто крашится, так как данные не могу загрузится. так вот, можно ли остановить функцию или же продолжить ее выполнение но уже в фоне?

Comment: Если данные уже прилетели, может стоит просто метод заново запускать этот, а если уходите в бекграунд просто его отменять, или вы в бекграунде хотите дожидать ответа от сервера?

Comment: Я сделал все таки повторную загрузку функции при ошибке, при выходе в фон выдаёт ошибку, при вхоже в активное состояние опять грузится функция. А как сделать отмену при выходе в фон?